# Installing Python's libxml2dom on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: python, xml, libxml2

Interested in using libxml2dom in a Python script of mine to (obviously) parse some XML.

When I attempt to import "libxml2dom" I receive the error message "ImportError: No module named libxml2dom"

- I can't seem to find it in the apt-get repo
- It doesn't seem to be present within easy_install.
- I already have libxml2 installed.

How can I / where can I install this from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) install works for me on Ubuntu 11.04 (python 2.7)

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ sudo pip install libxml2dom
```

Comment: that was exactly it. wasn't aware of pip until now. thanks very much :)